# How to Dispaly Total Count Result in new Column

Tags: mysql, count

i am trying to calculate **status** from one table and total status count but it is display in same column the query is

```
select Status ,count(Status) from assigntask group by status union all
SELECT count(Status) , count(Status) as total from assigntask ;
```

And Reslut Show Like This

```
Status    Count
Complete    1
Delay       2
  3         3
```

can it possible no of count "3" will show in another column?

For Example

```
Status   Count   Total
Complete   1       3
Delay      2
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'another column'. Can you also also show what your expected result is?

Comment: Add an example of your expected result

Comment: Total Count Value which is display in end i want to show that value in another column .. can we display total(3) in other column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a dummy field in both selects for the union to match up.

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(Status) as count, NULL as total FROM assigntask GROUP BY status 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, COUNT(Status), COUNT(Status) FROM assigntask;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Status ,count(Status), null as totalCount from assigntask group by status union all
SELECT 'Total status' , null,  count(Status) from assigntask ;
```

It is not exactly your desired result but I think this result is better than your result in rational display.

It will generate this result:

```
Status         Count     Total
Complete       1         null
Delay          2         null  
Total status   null      3
```

Comment: Thank You its also ok for me :)

Comment: Glad, I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Status, count(Status) as cnt, t.total
from assigntask
cross join (
    SELECT count(Status) as total from assigntask
) t
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have the total value in the first row you can use this query:

```
select t1.* from (
    select Status, count(Status) as count, (select count(Status) from assigntask) as total
    from assigntask 
    group by Status limit 1) as t1
union all
select t2.* from (
    select Status, count(Status) as count, null as total
    from assigntask 
    group by Status limit 1,100000) as t2
```

And the result is

[image]

Another approach is like this:

```
select Status, count(Status) as count, (select count(Status) from assigntask) as total
from assigntask 
group by Status
```

which gives following result

[image]

Personally I would use two, separate simple queries:

```
select Status, count(Status) as count
from assigntask 
group by Status;

select count(Status) as total from assigntask;
```